# Как вызвать intellisense в vs code на mac os high sierra

Tags: macos, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Через контрол пробел не вызывает, меняет язык. Даже если выключить изменения языка через контрол пробел то всеравно не вызывает.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 1):

вот настройки из линуха

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+space",
  "command": "editor.action.triggerSuggest",
  "when": "editorHasCompletionItemProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+space",
  "command": "editor.action.triggerParameterHints",
  "when": "editorHasSignatureHelpProvider && editorTextFocus"
}
```

файл -> параметры -> сочетания клавиш

ищите `editor.action.triggerSuggest` и `editor.action.triggerParameterHints`

Comment: Ну я же написал, что через контрол пробел меняет язык. Переназначил на option+space

Comment: @НазарКалитюк, ясное дело, что меняет язык. это в настройках осьХ менять. вопрос же стоит не как сделать по ctrl+space а ©Как вызвать intellisense в vs code на mac os high sierra

Answer (score 0):

В MacOS, для vscode по умолчанию, подсказки вызываются сочетанием клавиш command+i
Если это не работает, смотрите свои настройки в Keyboard Shortcuts для editor.action.triggerSuggest

Если указанное сочетание клавиш не работает, то нужно убедится:

1. Что данное сочетание не используется системой
2. Что раскладка клавиатуры соответствует языку указанной в настройках.

[image: Настройки горячих клавиш]